# Is there a way to know if a person has clicked on "Save" button for GPay

Tags: c#, callback, google-pay

I created C# Web Application and a table in SQL Server.

Now, I want to save the `objectId` and `loyalty Points` (balance) in this SQL table after the user clicks on "Save" button so that I can check whether he already saved the pass or not.

[image: The button]

I don't know how to add something like an `onClick` attribute to the save button. Is there a way to get a response from Google that allows me to do an action whenever the button is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

The [Save to Google Pay button](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/reference/s2w-reference) includes an `onsuccess` callback after the user has successfully saved the pass.

FYI, there are new versions of the button that play nicer with JavaScript frameworks and client side updates: https://github.com/google-pay/save-to-google-pay-button